# Proof that $\frac{a}{b}$ where $a , b \in \mathbb{N} $ must have at most one even.

Tags: real-analysis

As part of a proof I saw that if a rational number  $\frac{a}{b}$ is in lowest terms, then at most one of $a$ and $b$ can be even. Can anyone show me a simple proof of this?

Comment: If they are both even than they are not in lowest terms as you can divide both by $2$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

By contradiction, assume that both $a$ and $b$ are even. Hence we can write:

$$a=2\cdot m,\quad \text{and}\, b=2\cdot n$$
for some $m$, $n$ in $\mathbb{N}$. Therefore:

$$\frac{a}{b}=\frac{2\cdot m}{2\cdot n}=\frac{m}{n}$$

which implies that in fact $\frac{a}{b}$ is not in lowest terms, a contradiction.

Comment: No need to use contradiction. More constructively, if $a,b$ have a common factor $c > 1$ then cancelling it from top & bottom yields a lower terms equivalent fraction (this is the *contrapositive* of the OP's statement, which yields an *algorithm* to reduce a fraction to lowest terms).